# failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALIDE_APK]

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've a problem when I try to install the application that I'm developing. I'm working in Android Studio and when I try to launch my application on real device or an emulator, I get this message :

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/lexique"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/lexique
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

Before I switched to Android studio, I didn't have this problem but the development of applications with Android Studio is really nice. Is the problem related to the Android Studio App or something else?

Comment: What's the output of adb logcat when you try to install the APK? The full one.

Comment: Sorry can you give more details when you said "try to install the APK" because I don't see how I can install the APK. Thanks.

Comment: When you are exporting the APK you have some export log?

Comment: When I'm lauching the app, I've this log: Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5554 (Lexique)
Uploading file
 local path: /home/afk/workspace/Lexique/Lexique/build/apk/Lexique-debug-unaligned.apk
 remote path: /data/local/tmp/lexique
Installing lexique
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/lexique"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/lexique
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

Comment: I am asking about the building of the APK itself and not about the installation of it.

Comment: You want the ouput of Event log, no ?

Comment: How can I build the apk for to have the message that you asking me ?

Comment: Looks like you might be installing an intermediate version rather than an installable one - normally you want an apk that is both aligned & signed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably reason is bad package name when you create project. Package name must contain "." for example: "this.is.myapplication".

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55841